# NameError: global name is not defined in MyClass.py

Tags: python

I am running an example in a Python book for classes.

***MyClass.py***

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, Name="Sam", Age=32):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Age = Age

    def GetName(self):
        return self.Name

    def SetName(self, Name):
        self.Name = Name

    def GetAge(self):
        return self.Age

    def SetAge(self, Age):
        self.Age = Age

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} is aged {1}.".format(self.Name, self.Age)
```

***MyClassTest.py***

```
import MyClass

SamsRecord = MyClass.MyClass()
AmysRecord = MyClass.MyClass("Amy", 44)

print(SamsRecord.GetAge())
SamsRecord.SetAge(33)

print(AmysRecord.GetName())
AmysRecord.SetName("Aimee")

print(SamsRecord)
print(AmysRecord)
```

When I run MyClassTest.py, I got the following error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "MyClassTest.py", line 3, in <module>
SamsRecord = MyClass.MyClass() File "MyClass.py", line 3, in __init__ self.Name = Name
NameError: global name 'Name' is not defined
```

---

Any suggests on how to fix the error?

Comment: The argument is `name`, not `Name`.

Comment: Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: Typo Name to name

Comment: as an aside, try to use lowercase names for your variables to distinguish them from classes: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, name="Sam", Age=32):
    self.Name = Name
    self.Age = Age
```

typing error, you are trying to set self.Name to Name but in the parameters you called it name instead of Name
so try this:

```
def __init__(self, Name="Sam", Age=32):
    self.Name = Name
    self.Age = Age
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `self.Name = Name` to `self.Name = name` because the pamameter is `name` and not `Name`. Moreover, in this declaration `def SetAge(self, Name):`, it should be `def SetAge(self, Age):` because there's not argument `Name` as such (which you are trying to set in the next line).